# Regex match matches one too many characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a need to perform a somewhat strange regular expression replacement.  I've just about got it worked out, but not quite.

I need to remove multiple substrings from a string where the substrings to remove are surrounded by square braces `[]` *except* where the square braces are followed by two hashtags `[]##`.

For instance, if the original string is:

```
[phase]This is []a test [I]## of the emergency broadcast system. [28]##[test]xyz
```

Then the expected output after the regex replace would be:

```
This is a test [I]## of the emergency broadcast system. [28]##xyz
```

So far, I've tried a few things, but the closest regex pattern string I've come up with is `"\[[^\]]*\][^##]"`.  The problem with this is that it matches one more character than it should.  For instance, using the test string above, and doing the regex replace with an empty string, it returns:

```
his is  test [I]## of the emergency broadcast system. [28]##yz
```

What is the regex pattern string for which I'm searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your additional part,

```
[^##]
```

will match the next character that is *not* a # character. You need a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\[[^\]]*\](?!##)
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian! That passes my test and is exactly what I was looking for.  I experimented with the negative look ahead but obviously didn't get it right.

Comment: @STLDeveloper does it pass the `[28]##[test]` string making it `[28]##`?

Comment: @AgentFire, yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `"\[[^\]]*\][^##]"` with `"(\[[^\]]*\])(([^#]{2})?)"`.

First, your `[^##]` does not follow the rule "**except where the square braces are followed by two hashtags []##**". So it has to be changed to two non-sharpsigh chars.

Second, try replacing like this:

```
var s= Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$2");
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I run that against my test string I get `"is is test [I]## of the emergency broadcast system. [28]##z"`. It's actually taking two too many characters now instead of one too many.

Comment: @STLDeveloper this is because you replaces the whole regular expression instead of replacing the only captured group.

Comment: My regex replace statement looks like this `string s = Regex.Replace(input, pattern);`  I followed your instructions and replaced my pattern with the one you suggested and got the output I showed above.